# Here Javascript CORS header missing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, here-api

I use the Javascript API within an Angular Project. I'm using HTTPS connection. It all worked the last months but since last week, I don't get any Tiles loaded.
To a lot of requests, I get the response:

> 403 "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource."

Sometimes the request is successful and I get a Tile and the correct cors header, but that is only 1 of 20 requests I think.

Did I miss some API changes? Is this only on my side or are there any others affected?

Comment: Dis u put your service layer in different domain ??

Comment: no, all on the same domain

Comment: Any other error in the javascript console? Can you add the part where you are initializing `H.service.Platform` ?

Comment: Kindly provide screenshot from browser network with the details it will help so much in digging the error

Comment: ok, found the problem: credentials (app_id, app_code) were not valid any more...

Answer (score 0):

You can always **Enable CORS by returning correct headers**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    string

Access-Control-Allow-Methods    string

Access-Control-Allow-Origin     string
```

For more details -
https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/api-reference-swagger.html

https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/vector-tiles-api/dev_guide/topics/http-response-codes.html